# Javafx error on Ubuntu while using netbeans

Tags: linux, netbeans, javafx

When trying to run a basic javafx application on ubuntu linux, I am seeing the following error. The error appears while using either the commandline or netbeans to run the application.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/venkat/.m2/repository/com/oracle/javafx/javafx/2.1.0-beta/i386/libglass.so
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:277)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:90)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/venkat/.m2/repository/com/oracle/javafx/javafx/2.1.0-beta/i386/libglass.so
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1828)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:143)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:56)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:31)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application$1.run(Application.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:73)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:85)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.<clinit>(GtkPlatformFactory.java:23)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:20)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:108)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exception is caused because maven is unable to find the native libraries on the classpath.

**Netbeans**

You can solve the problem by adding JVM argument inside the run profile.

`-Djava.library.path=/home/venkat/Programs/javafx/2.1.0-beta/rt/lib/i386/`

*Image*

[image]

**Command line**

If you face the same problem while trying to run the app on the commandline, the following exports should fix it.

```
export JAVAFX_HOME=/home/venkat/Programs/javafx/2.1.0-beta

export CLASSPATH=\$JAVAFX_HOME/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/venkat/Programs/javafx/2.1.0-beta/rt/lib/i386/
```

The first two env variables above fix a classpath problem which is seen when javafx runtime cannot be found.