# How to use JavaFX in OpenJDK7

Tags: javafx, java

I am using eclipse and openjdk-7.
I want to use JavaFX classes in my project, but it doesn't work and give me this error:

```
Can't load library .../libglass.so
```

I set the JAVA_HOME & JAVA but it doesn't works.
What should I do?

Comment: Take a look for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009066/javafx-error-on-ubuntu-while-using-netbeans

Comment: That is for using netbeans, i am using eclipse.

Comment: you can apply the same principle. you must add the same line to `Run configurations`->`Your run configuration`->`Arguments`->`VM arguments`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, anyway, Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you customized the line using your folders?

Answer (score 1):

If You have to add **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar** in your classpath then it will work in eclipse.

Comment: If i don't add this, it got error and don't let me to compile, but the error i said is runtime error